# sUnity shooting with Tongue 2d game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So, I was able to create a very simple 2D shooter, where my character shoots a bullet at the enemy. It very cool I guess :) , but I would like to use his tongue: so, instead of shooting a bullet, it goes toward the enemy, licks it, and the tongue comes back.

I'm wondering how I can do this ? Shall I use a LineRender-er or what?

Right now, I have the following structure:

- GameObject: Character
- It's child: characterGUN
  which fires a bullet.

You can see the bullets here, which fired from the reptile in the left bottom corner.

[image]

Comment: yes, use line renderer

Comment: can you please add some example for me as an answer ? I would be delighted to accept it. I'm really don't know who to solve to back movment.