# Unity 2D tongue shooter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I would like to use a characters tongue so instead of shooting a bullet, it goes toward the enemy, licks it, and comes back. I got this wording from this question: [Unity shooting with Tongue 2d game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070035/unity-shooting-with-tongue-2d-game) (hasn't been answered and is 4+ years old). The only difference is my character moves.

I have this code from looking at a shooting tutorial so when you click the tongue prefab generates and is at the correct angle. I need it to grow on click and shrink back.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 target;
    public GameObject crosshairs;
    public GameObject tonguePrefab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        target = transform.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z));
        crosshairs.transform.position = new Vector2(target.x, target.y);

        Vector3 difference = target - player.transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            shootTongue(rotationZ);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator shootTongue(float rotationZ)
    {
        GameObject t = Instantiate(tonguePrefab) as GameObject;
        t.transform.position = new Vector2(target.x, target.y);
        t.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2000);

        t.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I was also trying to make it disappear after whatever time and with that it doesn't work at all?

Comment: hmmm could you maybe provide a quick drawing of the effect you're after - so we're sure we know what you want? (also considering your profile picture, i'm guessing you have some artistic knowledge so that shouldn't be hard ;))

Answer (score 0):

If the prefab is just a line with a simple texture I suggest using a line renderer:

1. Create an empty transform that starts on the mouth and then it move untill it reaches the crosshair. The movement is done using [Vector2.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html).
2. Your tongue will no be a line renderer component. This line renderer will have 2 points, the start which is static, and the end which you have to update on the Update() for example, to correspond to the positions of the empty transform in item 1.

If you really wish to expand a tongue gameobject instead, then you are going to need a bit of math, this answer has what you need but in 3D:
    https://answers.unity.com/questions/473076/scaling-in-the-forward-direction.html

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials or examples for any of this? The final link is just a post and I would like something with a little more explanation

Answer (score 0):

1) I suggest creating sprite/sprite sheet animations with [Mecanim](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html) or relatively new Skeletal Animation with [Anima2D](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/skeletal-animation-with-anima2d). With these systems you can create nice animations, transitions, even animate the sphere collider to trigger collisions and actions, change active state of your objects, etc. and control the animation with very little code. This way you can get best effects in my opinion.

As tongue is not a bullet... :) You only need one. I don't think you want to Instantiate/Create prefabs every time you press the lick button. Instead you should just turn your tongue object on/off (gameObject.SetActive). You can also change your object active state within the animation. So if you don't know how to code it you can do most of it in the Animation window and use very simple code to play the animation when you press the lick button. Whenever a sphere collider touches something you can tell the Animator Controller to play a 'roll back' animation and it will transition nicely to the start position.

There are many tutorials about Mecanim, Animations, 2D Animations, Anima2D, Animator Controller out there.

2) If you need very good control over the tongue you could create a custom mesh and control it via script but this is far more difficult.

3) The reason why your object is not turning off is probably because you wrote WaitForSeconds(2000) so it will turn off after 2000 seconds - more than half an hour. You should also call it with StartCoroutine(shootTongue()) as it is a Coroutine. Again if you want to turn off the object don't create new ones every time. If you want to keep creating new objects you should Destroy the objects instead. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of deactivated tongues in your scene and I don't think you needs that many tongues.